# function name as a string

Tags: java, function, generics, java-8

I am trying to wrap my head around generic and functions... what I am trying to achieve: Passing function **name** as a **string** to get it executed:

I want to do `Wrapper.useFunction("eleven")` or `Wrapper.useFunction("ten")`

```
public class Wrapper<T> {
    public F useFunction(Function<F, F> function) {
        return function.apply(F);
    }

    Function<F, String> ten = s -> "10";
    Function<F, String> eleven = s -> "11";
}
```

But this code not even close to compiling. Maybe it doesn't make any sense. Any suggestions?

Comment: Look up reflection.

Comment: I saw example with reflections. Isn't there way to do that with java 8 without reflections?

Comment: It would not be wise to waste time trying. Reflection was built for this.

Comment: @PutinasPiliponis No. The only way to call function using string with function name, is the use of reflection.

Comment: if you don't want to use reflection, you can replace `String` with your own enum class. for example: `wrapper.use(ELEVEN)`

Comment: name of 'external' variable holding object is not known to reflection code inside. Exaple: 2 or more references can point to the same object

Comment: Java isn't meant for this, it's type-safe for a reason. What are you trying to do (other than passing strings as function names, I mean)? Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a finite set of functions which you would like to be able to call I would recommend building a Map which maps Strings to instances of Runnable (or similar functional interfaces). Your useFunction method may then look up the function implementation in the Map and call it if it exists.

Example:

```
public class SomeClass {

    private final Map<String, Runnable> methods = new HashMap<>();
    {
        methods.put("helloworld", () -> {
            System.out.println("Hello World!");
        });
        methods.put("test", () -> {
            System.out.println("test!");
        });
        methods.put("doStuff", () -> {
            System.out.println("doStuff!");
        });
    }

    public void perform(String code) {
        methods.getOrDefault(code, 
            () -> {
                System.err.println("No such Method: "+code);
            })
        .run();
    }

}
```

If you want to call arbitrary methods you should probably use Reflection as stated by others.